# Can I apply the closed graph Theorem in the proof of the corollary of Lumer Philips?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Consider [Yosida, Functional analysis, reprint of the edition 1980] at p.251, in particular the proof of the corollary (of Lumer Philips theorem) which states that if $A \colon D(A) \subset X \to R(A)\subset X  $ is a densely defined closed linear operator on a Banach space $X$ and such that $A$, $A^*$ are both dissipative, then $A$  generates a contraction semigroup.

In this short proof Yosida proves that $(I-A)^{-1} \colon R(I-A) \subset X \to X$ is closed and continuous. Then he wants to prove that $R(I-A)=X$ and he does it by contradiction.

But the fact that $R(I-A)=X$ does not immediately follow from the closed graph theorem?
Indeed by the closed graph th. as $(I-A)^{-1} \colon R(I-A) \subset X \to X$ is closed and continuous, we should have immediately  $X=D((I-A)^{-1})=R(I-A)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I cannot follow what you are trying to do. Are you saying that if you have a bounded operator $T:D\to X$ defined on a dense subset $D\subset X$, then the fact that $T$ is bounded implies that $D=X$?

Comment: Yes, I have this version of the closed graph theorem which states: any of the two  following conditions imply the third: 1) A is continuous 2) A is closed, 3) D(A)=X. Is this correct?

Comment: (a bounded operator on a dense domain can be uniquely extended to all X thanks to the bounded inverse theorem)

Comment: Why would the fact that you can *extend* from $D(A)$ to $X$ imply that $D(A)=X$?